# convert varchar2 to date type

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a create_date field of type varchar2(). There are invalid values ​​like this:

[image]

[image]

How can I exclude them so that I can insert them from this table into another table in a field with a date value?
I need correctly entered dates like 10/02/2022, 08/05/2021, etc.

Comment: Which database version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`validate_conversion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) function to filter rows that contain invalid string representation of a date:

```
with a(dt) as (
  select *
  from sys.odcivarchar2list(
  '21.10.2022',
  '31.02.2022',
  'Не дата',
  '01.12.2021',
  '00.10.2021',
  '   '
  )
)
select
  dt as char_value,
  to_date(dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as date_value
from a
where validate_conversion(dt as date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') = 1
```

| CHAR_VALUE | DATE_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 21.10.2022 | 2022-10-21 00:00:00 |
| 01.12.2021 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ofzOfEOn)